# Code first not putting Dictionary property of class into database, ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dictionary, entity-framework-migrations, dbset

I'm building my first biggish web app in ASP.NET MVC using Code First migrations. Every other class is being updated in the database whenever I alter it, but not this class.  The UserID and Wallet are being saved, but the Dictionary is always null when referenced in code (even directly after I fill it, save db changes, then extract userproperties again), and there is no mention of it in either dbo.UserProperties or dbo.Media.

Is it maybe not possible to do this? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Class:

```
public class UserProperties
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual Wallet Wallet { get; set; }
    public virtual IDictionary<string,Media> Images{  get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading the following it seems it because of the string key. It needs a class that I wrote.

[Entity Framework Code First List<string> Property Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317749/entity-framework-code-first-liststring-property-mapping)

Answer (score 1):

You should use **ICollection** instead of a Dictionary

Dictionary is not supported in EF5/6. You must use traditional one-to-many relation.