# List of String Entity Framework Mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, nopcommerce

How can we map a  List Email addresses with a table using Code First Approach where List is filled in One Action Method and been sent to another Action Method (Data is getting Null between to Action Methods although it is between same controller and i have initialize the List at class Level. I found only one resource on the topic

[Entity Framework Code First List<string> Property Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317749/entity-framework-code-first-liststring-property-mapping).

Which is not clearing my doubts, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just converted the list to XML and store it in the database and while picking up the data i re-converted them