# Using Entity Framework mapping generic list List<string> to the sql server table column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm working on create a SQL Server database table with different column to save the data but in my class definition their is a property List and I'm wondering how to create a column which will capture data from generic list.

Here is my sample class:

```
public Class CustomerData 
{   
      public long Id {get; set;}   
      public string Title {get; set;}   
      public List<String> Tags {get; set} 
}
```

I'm not using Code First approach, I'm manually mapping the class properties to table column after creating entity context because my class is part of different library and I don't have access to it.

Any input is helpful.

Comment: I would create a table with a foreign key for the items in the list because what would happen if the list contained 1000+ entries?

Comment: Thanks Guruprasad for formatting my question and providing the valuable input. We're still debating the approach to consider and the following article (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317749/entity-framework-code-first-liststring-property-mapping) also provide a good input.