# Input for List<string>

Tags: c#, jquery, razor

I have a `View Model` as follow:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public List<string> Mac { get; set; }
}
```

And Action under User Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Register()
 {
     return View();
 }
```

I created a view for this action with the scaffolding tool, in the generated code, there is no input for my Mac property. How can I create a dynamic input for my List? I want an input field where new input will be added through jQuery.

Comment: Do you expect user can input multiple values to `Mac` or only single?

Comment: if you wan to use multiple input for `Mac`, How many input do you need?

Comment: Since you're using Code First, take a look for this: [EF Code First for `List<string>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317749/entity-framework-code-first-liststring-property-mapping/8325078#8325078).

Comment: @D-Shih  First Time Single Input field. Then extra input field(s) will be generated using Jquery.

Comment: This is not the standard behavior, I've edited your question.